# Why is this spoon bent sideways

Tags: utensils

Can anyone ID this spoon? I took over a small kitchen and they have this thing. You can ignore the meat sticker, it’s a kosher thing.
[image: curved spoon]

Comment: I really think it's just a spoon that was bent

Comment: It's the spoon from The Matrix, bent by the one himself. Worth a fortune

Comment: There is no spoon @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, there is only yourself.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper not in that axis.  The metal would be far too stiff to do that outside a factory.  I suspect the extra-blunt tip is deliberate too

Comment: For stirring around corners?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If it is normal table spoon or dessert spoon sized, it is a spoon adjusted for people with limited mobility.

When adjusting for an individual, you would usually adjust the plastic as that is easier, but this is likely been factory adjusted, being a common enough adjustment that it is made in decent numbers.

I have considered training in the field but did not. Such a spoon was an example the school did show in the introduction material.

Comment: As a lefty I would struggle with such a spoon ...

Comment: Your definition of "adjusted" must be different than mine.  The spoon was quite obviously manufactured to that shape.

Comment: @DavidPostill But not if it came in a set https://www.caregiverproducts.com/melaware-cutlery.html

Comment: @MarkRansom "adapted" might be better - but it could be said the design was adjusted.

Comment: Some leeway please, English is not my first language. An edit for the right word is acceptable @MarkRansom

Comment: @MarkRansom I see nothing wrong with the word "adjusted" here, I just read it as "the spoon's _design_ was adjusted" rather than "the spoon itself was adjusted".

Answer (score 26):

The same kind of spoon is also sold as “learning spoon” for small children that start feeding themselves.

The key is that these angled spoons can be held by grabbing the handle with the fist, which needs fewer fine motor skills than the three-finger grip more customarily used by adults.

Comment: Also 'limited mobility' in a way. But for a different reason.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a spoon for the elderly.   I have seen them in nursing homes.  If that logo was always there, it's probably a promotional item.

Comment: The logo/sticker is for kosher purposes. No mixing of milk and meat; people who observe strictly have separate utensils for each.

Comment: @Damila Though the thought of eating any kind of meat with a spoon is thoroughly unappetizing.  Adds credence to the theory of it being made for young children, since their food is often pureed.  Though I suppose that's true of some elderly people as well...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's not really the point here, but for example chicken soup would use a spoon and require the 'meaty' cutlery for strict kosher purposes

Comment: @dbmag9 Ah, soup, good call, didn't think about that.  Though this looks a little small for a soup spoon, but whatever.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Something as simple as serving cranberry sauce with meat might need a 'meaty' spoon if the owner was sufficiently observant and wanted to wash the spoon together with the rest of the meat dishes. The rules concern a religious definition of 'cross-contamination' so are more stringent than simply whether the item comes into contact with meat.

Answer (score 0):

Such spoons have been around for a long time. Initially, most of them were tea-spoon size and bent this way primarily to make it easier for mothers to feed their babies and toddlers. In the olden times (when high chairs were even more expensive and considered a luxury and just for the privileged), mothers, nannies or baby sitters used to feed infants by sitting at the table and holding infants in their lap. Therefore, a bent spoon came in handy. Later on, as society progressed, they started manufacturing everyday utensils and products specifically designed for the disabled, for the left handed and so on.